# How good do two scatter plots "match"?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, scatter

I'm not sure if "match" is really the right word, but I have to scatter plots of the following form.

[image]
[image]

I'd like to compare the two, but I'm not really sure how to do that. When I say compare I mean I want to know "how similar" the two plots are to each other. So the first question would be what method you could use to achieve that and the second how would I realize that.

The plots were generated with a modified version (no information about the intensity) of [this](http://marksolters.com/programming/2015/02/27/rgb-histograph.html) code.

So is there a way in python to do something like that?

Thanks, Sito.

Comment: What is "the two"? What exactly is the question? What would you like to achieve? What problem do you have in getting there? See [ask].

Comment: Added a clearer question and a second image (not sure how to post it like you did).

Comment: Are you trying to find out how similar the plots are or how similar the data is?

Comment: The idea was to find out how similar the plots are but I'm not sure what exactly the difference is. I mean, how is it different to compare the plots of the data and the data itself? The goal is to find out how similar the color distribution of two pictures is, in this case the both plots.

Comment: The similarity is 42. Joking aside, you need to first find a good measure of similarity. This is not the place to ask for a tutorial about similarity measures. Once you have a clear idea about that, you may try to implement that and if there is a problem with that implementation, Stackoverflow would be a good place to ask about this problem.

Comment: I really don't think you should be comparing the plots. You should be comparing the data. And it's impossible to recommend techniques for that without seeing examples of the data.

Answer (score 2):

In the comments I claimed that the similarity between the two plots would be 42. Here is why:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# read in the two images
a = plt.imread("data/sim1.png")
b = plt.imread("data/sim2.png")
# define a similarity measure, 
# here we take the sum of the squares of the distances between pixels
similarity = np.ceil(np.sum((a-b)**2)/1000.)
print(similarity)
# this prints 42.0
```